# ¿Cómo puedo mandar datos que bajé con Python a un Excel ya existente?

Tags: python

Estoy bajando datos de Twitter y los estoy almacenando en un Excel.
Quiero hacerlo diariamente y guardar todos estos datos en el mismo Excel, pero en distintas hojas, es decir, que cada día se cree una hoja nueva pero en el mismo libro.

Hasta ahora, lo que hace mi código es bajar los datos y guardarlos en un nuevo Excel, es decir un Excel por día.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import GetOldTweets3 as got
import pandas as pd



keywords = ['saqueo chile', 'vandalismo chile', 'delincuencia chile','ataque carabinero', 'ataque comisaria','ataque subcomisaria',' manifestacion chile', 'protesta chile', 'bomba molotov','coctel molotov', 'funa chile', 'incendio intencional','quema transantiago', 'matapaco', '#matapaco', '#chiledesperto','#piñeraculiao', '#renunciapiñera', 'plaza de la dignidad' ,'#chaopiñera', '#primeralinea' ,'incendio iglesia', '#piensaprensa','#chileoculto', '#plazadeladignidad', '#ElPeorGobiernoDeLaHistoria']
user = 'piensaprensa'

#para tomar tweets del dia hoy
# since_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# until_date = (datetime.today()+ timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

#para tomar tweets de ayer
since_date = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
until_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


region = "Santiago, Chile"
milles = "10mi"

text_tweets = []
for keyword in keywords:
    # Creation of query object
    tweetCriteria = (got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch(keyword).setSince(since_date).setUntil(until_date).setNear(region).setWithin(milles))
    tweets = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
    text_tweets += [[tweet.date, tweet.text, keyword] for tweet in tweets]
#creation of dataframe
tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(text_tweets, columns=['Datetime', 'Text', 'keyword'])
print(tweets_df.shape)

with pd.ExcelWriter('tweets.xlsx', mode='a' , options= {'remove_timezone': True}) as writer:
    tweets_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Dia_{}'.format(since_date))
```

Answer (score 1):

Realmente no estas creando un archivo Excel  sino un archivo separado por comas y a este no puedes añadirle hojas de cálculo. Para hacer lo que quieres tienes que usar un formato Excel y añadir de la siguiente forma:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('tweets.xlsx', mode='a',engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    tweets_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Dia_{}'.format(since_date))
```

Es importante el parámetro **mode='a'** puesto que indica que agregue, de lo contrario lo crea.

**EDICION:** Si utilizas el mode='a' debes especificar engine='openpyxl' (lo agregué a la solución.  El archivo creado la primera vez:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('tweets.xlsx') as writer:
    tweets_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Dia_{}'.format(since_date))
```

Comment: Probé con lo que me dijiste pero tuve el siguiente error "Excel does not support datetimes with timezones. Please ensure that datetimes are timezone unaware before writing to Excel." Entonces agregué la opción de "remove_timezone" pero sigue arrojando el mismo error. Edito mi publicación para que veas lo que hice.

Comment: Utiliza los parámetros date_format y datetime_format del ExcelWriter.. ¿Que versión de Python y pandas usas?

Comment: ¿Tu campo de fecha en que formato está? Quizá sea útil si es que capturas el status.timestamp_ms yo lo converti a fecha y hora con **datetime.utcfromtimestamp(status.timestamp_ms/1000).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")**

Comment: mis versiones son Python: 3.7.4, pandas: 0.25.3 . El tiempo lo traigo a partir del ´.date´ que es una clase de GetOldTweets, y me lo trae en como (datetime) en UTC. Podrías agregar lo que me dices en los comentarios a tu respuesta?

Comment: Ok. Muéstrale un ejemplo del valor fecha que tienes.

Comment: Puedes incluir el df_tweets.head(5) para darme una idea de los datos. Voy a editar la respuesta para incluir lo que indico en los comentarios pero quisiera saber exactamente como son tus datos. Por otro lado, en  text_tweets  puedes probar usando tweet.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").

Comment: Un ejemplo de fecha es 2020-01-29 13:47:04+00:00. No entiendo muy bien lo que me estas pidiendo que te muestre.  Mi problema ahora vendria a ser que excel no soporta datetimes with timezones, como puedo solucionar eso?

Comment: Quítale el +000 final que es lo que te está dando problema. Pruébalo poniendo la fecha como %Y-%m-%d para ver si pasa. La verdad que siempre he usado el DateTime normal son el +000 final.  Haré una prueba.

Comment: Me sirvió agregar esto  tweet.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") para que se no se baje la hora que es lo que me molestaba, de todas formas me sigue insistiendo con el error de timezone. Voy a intentar otra variante para el proyecto. De todas formas, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Pero si la columna de fecha la pusiste con **strftime** entonces esa columna dejó de ser de tipo fecha porque la función devuelve **string** o la vuelves a convertir en **datetime*? Si la vuelve a convertir usa el parámetro del *datetime tzinfo=None**. Yo uso esa sentencia sin problemas y fechas de tipo 2020-01-19 13:07:03 . ¿Solo para quitar las dudas puedes hacerlo sin esa columnq?